# Set Windows Commandline (or PowerShell) to connect to internet via Proxy

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, proxy, powershell

I work behind a very strict firewall but I am able to browse (most) of the internet just fine with FireFox and I.E., however there are specific proxy settings to have. Namely, an autoconfig *.pac link that gives the settings.

Anyway, I am trying to run some Maven through commandline/powershell and it requires downloading something. Now, the file it wants to download works fine in IE/Firefox ([this](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom)) however in cmnd/pshell it times out. In fact, I can't even ping external sites using cmd/pshell.

So, I think I realized I need to make sure that when cmd/pshell sends a request over the internet, it at least utalizes the I.E. proxy settings. How can I ensure it is doing that?

Comment: For PowerShell your script needs to be programmed to use the proxy - AFAIK you can't just set it system-wide for all PowerShell downloads.  See this StackOverflow question: [PowerShell, Web Requests, and Proxies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571429/powershell-web-requests-and-proxies)

Comment: I understand system wide can't work, but I was hoping to set some environmental variable that will enable it to work. That link you provided didn't work. It was geared toward PowerShell -- I'd kind of prefer CommandLine though since all the guides specify command line to run Maven.